# Forecasting noise data

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

My data contains no trend or seasonality, but contains noise. While I use ARIMA to forecast it, the model is (1,0,0). In addition to this if I use dayOfWeek and a promotion predictor I get a forecast with a sequence repeating itself. I don't trust this forecast. Is there a better model for forecasting my data? Below is a STL decomposition plot of my data. First plot attached is a promotion data. [image]

[image: STL decompose]

Comment: You really need to be more specyfic for this to be answerable. Please edit to add more details. If your data is noise-only, then probably the best you can get is to use the mean as your forecast.

Comment: Thanks Tim for the revert. Added to the question a plot of STL decomposition of my dataset. Does this help specifying my question?

Comment: It does help. So your data is daily, and the "time" probably refers to weeks? Can you please add a plot indicating when promotions happened (was there only a single kind of promotion), plus the forecast of your model including day of week, and the output of your model?

Comment: Yes, my data is daily and "time" refers to weeks. I have added a plot of the promotions values. My model is (1,0,0) with following coefficients: dayOfWeek as 0.3920 and promotion as 0.3070

Comment: Please post the actual data for both Y and the promotion.